# Python - Split String Containing '\x'

Tags: python, split

I want only the number here which is in scientific notation. The output below is the Python interpreter output from Terminal. How would one go about this.

Added info: the string isn't always the same length so no char. length shortcuts... The suffix is also not always the same.

```
>>> x
[' 1.9580000000000002E-05\xef\xbb\xbf\r\n']
>>> x[0].split('\\')
[' 1.9580000000000002E-05\xef\xbb\xbf\r\n']
>>>
```

Desired output:

```
1.9580000000000002E-05
```

Comment: You say the string isn't always the same, but is the suffix always the same?

Comment: No, the suffix is not always the same.

Comment: So what other suffixes you could have? ie: what's the pattern?

Comment: your string doesn't actually contain an `'\x'` (it contains an `'\xef'` though).  check with `r'\x' in x[0]` to see for yourself!

Comment: Where does the data come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> x = [' 1.9580000000000002E-05\xef\xbb\xbf\r\n']
>>> float(re.search(r'\d\.\d*E[+-]\d+',x[0]).group())
1.9580000000000002e-05
```

But, depending on the encoding of your text and where you get that data from, this is possibly more "correct":

```
>>> float(x[0].decode('utf8').encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip())
1.9580000000000002e-05
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
input = ' 1.9580000000000002E-05\xef\xbb\xbf\r\n'
filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, input).strip()
float(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, input).strip())
```

Maybe this will help you understand your input:

```
>>> for i in input: print i, repr(i)
...
  ' '
1 '1'
. '.'
9 '9'
5 '5'
8 '8'
0 '0'
0 '0'
0 '0'
0 '0'
0 '0'
0 '0'
0 '0'
0 '0'
0 '0'
0 '0'
0 '0'
0 '0'
2 '2'
E 'E'
- '-'
0 '0'
5 '5'
∩ '\xef'
╗ '\xbb'
┐ '\xbf'
'\r'

'\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

`split` does not work because the string does not contain backslashes. \xef represents a single symbol which hexadecimal code is 0xEF. Python interpreter just pretty-prints the string for you.

The solution depends on what characters can appear and what can not. One example:

```
>>> ' 1.9580000000000002E-05\xef\xbb\xbf\r\n'.strip('\xef\xbb\xbf\r\n ')
'1.9580000000000002E-05'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either split on the character `\xef`

```
x[0].split('\xef')
```

or you have to use a raw string literal:

```
x = [r' 1.9580000000000002E-05\xef\xbb\xbf\r\n']
x[0].split('\\')
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is scientific notation and the number of places is going to be same before `\xef\xbb\xbf\r\n` then this should do the trick.

```
>>> x[:22]
'1.9580000000000002E-05'
```